# Perl writing to a 'memory file' plays tricks with pattern matching

Tags: regex, perl

When I run this code, I get "no" printed out:

```
my $memory_file;
my $fh;
open ($fh, '>', \$memory_file);
print $fh "abc";
if( $memory_file =~ m/^.*$/ )
{ print "yes\n" }
else
{ print "no\n" }
```

If I print out `$memory_file`, the contents are indeed `"abc"`.

If I change the pattern to `.*` (no `^` or `$`) it works as expected.

If I put the line `$memory_file = "abc"` before the match, I get 'yes' printed out (as originally expected).

What on earth is going on here?

(This is perl 5.14.1)

**Update:** Some more discussion on [PerlMonks](http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=945256). It is seeming like a bug, I will log it.

**Update 2:** The fine Perl developers have fixed this bug: https://rt.perl.org/rt3//Public/Bug/Display.html?id=108398

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the end of line character that is messing things up. While a regular assignment works:

```
my $str = "abc";
print "Works" if $str =~ /^.*$/;
```

...the code in the question does not. This regex should match *any* string, since it also matches the empty string. Even undefined values would match (though it would cause a warning). Also, `^.*` does match.

The only reasonable explanation is that for some reason, whatever check is performed to match an end of string, it is not finding it. The end of the string is missing.

Curiously, replacing `$` with `\z` works. But not `\Z`.

Adding a newline also works. Which would sort of make sense, as adding a newline would imply that an end of the string is also added, in the non-multiline regex sense.

I don't know the inner workings of why this happens, but I suspect that when using this particular form of "assignment", an end-of-the-string marker is never placed on the string. A sort of "raw" assignment, which confuses the check for end of string in the regex.

It feels like a bug. Perhaps this particular feature has not been properly maintained.

Comment: Just for another data point, printing `"abc\n"` to the mem file and matching against `^.*\n$` also fails (but succeeds with 'normal' strings). Matching `"abc\n"` with `^.*$` succeeds, as noted elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>I think problem is the newline and `$` anchor. It checks the string after the newline and your string has not it.</strike>

**EDIT**:

See a detail explanation of the problem in other answers because mine was incorrect. But I will give two options to solve it:

- Write "abc\n" to your file and check with `$`
- Check end of string with `\z`.

Comment: That is incorrect. `$  matches the end of the line (or before newline at the end)` See [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Metacharacters).

Comment: And even if it was correct, `.*` matches *any* string, since it also matches the empty string.

Comment: @TLP: You are right. I will delete my answer to avoid confusion.

Comment: @TLP: Finally I edited the answer by deleting the incorrect explanation. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

just use an auxiliary variable.

```
#$| = 1; # AutoFlush

my $memory_file;
open ( my $fh, '>>', \$memory_file) or die $!;
print $fh "abc";

my $buff = $memory_file;

if( $buff =~ m/^abc$/ ){ # or m/^.*$/
    print "yes\n"; 
}else{ 
    print "no\n";
}
```

Comment: That also works without concatenation: `my $buff = $memory_file`.

Comment: exactly! just use an auxiliary variable.

Comment: Storing it to a temporary variable does indeed work, so thank you for that. Do you have any handy explanation for this behavior?

Comment: Also, autoflush doesn't seem to change anything for me. Is it necessary? And if so is that documented somewhere? I am having trouble finding thorough docs for in-memory files, in general.

Comment: @jwd, `$| = 1;` autoflushes STDOUT. (Tehcnically, the currently `select`ed handle.) You want `$fh->autoflush(1);` instead.

Comment: You will not need the autoflush, can remove.
Use this module to work with "files in memory" : [IO::Scalar](http://search.cpan.org/~dskoll/IO-stringy-2.110/lib/IO/Scalar.pm)

Answer (score 0):

Well, my first instinct is to say that files in memory do not act the same as physical files. Try changing `print $fh "abc";` to `print $fh "abc\n";` to see if your input 'becomes' a line.

My other instinct is that your file isn't actually getting written to before you read from it. Flush your buffer with `$|++;`

So, try:

```
my $memory_file;
my $fh;
open ($fh, '>', \$memory_file);
print $fh "abc";
$|++;
if( $memory_file =~ m/^.*$/ )
{ print "yes\n" }
else
{ print "no\n" }
```

Comment: I think `$|++` is more like a configuration setting and should be set early on, rather than being treated as a way to trigger flushing.

Comment: What @PlatinumAzure said. And besides that, running the code you gave also prints 'no' on my system. Is it different for you?

Comment: `$| = 1;` autoflushes STDOUT. (Tehcnically, the currently `select`ed handle.) You want `$fh->autoflush(1);` instead.

Comment: @jwd I'm at my work computer and don't have a perl install right now. I should've tested it -_-